# Will RewriteRules In .htaccess Affect Site's Speed?

Tags: php, performance, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am planing to add at most 10 .htaccess rewrite url codes in home directory will it affect execution ( loading time of site ) of my website ?

my current .htaccess file is

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([^.]+).html index.php?perma=$3
RewriteRule ^movies/([^.]+).html gallery.php?movie=$1
RewriteRule ^album/([^.]+).html gallery.php?album=$1
RewriteRule ^img/([^.]+)/([^.]+).html gallery.php?img=$2
RewriteRule ^movies.html gallery.php
```

Comment: Will it have an impact? Yes. Will it be noticeable? No.

Comment: Run your website through [PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights) to learn about things you need to worry about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it will affect the load time. The more rules/exceptions you have, the longer it takes to render. But: we are talking about micro/milliseconds that won't be even noticed by the human eye.

Answer (score 2):

You might need to see [performance impact of order of rewrite rules when using apache mod_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6478346/performance-impact-of-order-of-rewrite-rules-when-using-apache-mod-rewrite) and, like @diolemo commented, for 20 rewrite rules it's not noticeable.

Answer (score 2):

10 rules are not a problem, but for future reference: The usual approach is to redirect everything to a single entry point and let the application do the routing. A simple example:

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L,QSA]
```

**index.php**

```
$query = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$queryParts = explode('/', $query);
switch($queryParts[0]) {
    case 'movies':
        // ...
        break;
    case 'album':
        // ...
        break;
    case 'img':
        // ...
        break;
    // ...
    default:
        // 404 not found
}
```

The `RewriteCond` conditions assure that requests to existing files are not rewritten. QSA is optional, it means "query string appended", so that for example `movies.html?sort=title` gets rewritten to `index.php?sort=title`. The original request URI is available in `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

If your application is object oriented, the [Front Controller](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/frontController.html) pattern will be of interest to you. All major PHP frameworks use it in some way, it might help to look at their implementations.

If not, a micro-framework like [Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/) could do the job for you. In Silex your routing could look as follows:

**index.php**

```
require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new Silex\Application();

$app->get('/{year}/{month}/{slug}', function ($year, $month, $slug) use ($app) {
    return include 'article.php';
});
$app->get('/movies/{movie}.html', function ($movie) use ($app) {
    return include 'gallery.php';
});
$app->get('/album/{album}.html', function ($album) use ($app) {
    return include 'gallery.php';
});
$app->get('/img/{parent}/{img}.html', function ($parent, $img) use ($app) {
    return include 'gallery.php';
});
$app->get('/movies.html', function () use ($app) {
    return include 'gallery.php';
});

$app->run();
```

`gallery.php` and `article.php` would have to *return* their output. You probably can reuse your existing scripts with this index.php if you replace `$_GET['var']` with `$var` and add output buffering:

**gallery.php**

```
ob_start();
// ...
return ob_get_clean();
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time needed to download a webpage comes from retrieving the HTML, CSS, JavaScript, and images. The time to rewrite the URL is negligible.

Usually, the images are the biggest cause of slow load times. A tool like Pingdom can help you put the load times of various components in perspective.

http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/

HTH.